# PHP Log file generation

Tags: php, logging, backend

just want to get some inputs, I'm currently working on a PHP process script that runs continously every 20 seconds, id connects to DB, do some processing, then talks to other server to transmit data.

Since its running on background, i track its state by generating a logfile, sometimes it takes a while to complete for several reasons, network connectivity(since it talks to other servers as well), database is busy, etc. At times it takes too long to complete and the web server actually terminates it. When this happens, the logs wasn't written because I only write it when the process ends, since it got terminated, it wasn't able to do it. I'm thinking on writing the log actively, rather than at the end of processing so i'll have a better idea where it stopped. Any suggestions or ideas on this matter?

Thank you!

I converted the logging to be as needed than wait for it to complete, but I'm a bit hesitant to roll it out because it might slow the processing down

Comment: Do some testing on real data then, if you're worried about performance

Comment: How did you run the script? Why can the web server terminate a background process?

Comment: @ADyson Hello, yeah I'll be testing on more a more realistic load, was just wondering if I can get some additional inputs on this matter, or something I need to take note or something

Comment: @shingo there's a cron job that runs it, the PHP-FPM is the one that terminates it if its takes too long

Comment: What shingo probably is referring to is that you can run PHP scripts in 2 ways: Directly or through the web server. The former will use the path to the PHP script, whereas the latter will have the complete URL in the command. Which one are you using and why?

Comment: Yes, scripts running in the command line should have unlimited execution time by default, so it's weired when you said that they were terminated.

Comment: oh okay, sorry I think i mixed it up for a bit.. basically I have 2 servers, the one that has a background process (Server A) that sends the processed data to another server (Server B - via curl) that does further processing of the data, so Server B is the one having issues if it takes a while to process. It gets terminated.

Comment: Cut out the curl request doing the actual processing, then. Just use that to provide the data to server B and indicate that a job needs to be done. Then have another cron job on server B check for newly requested jobs, and process them